# jpa mapping issue during insertion (parent/child) - cannot insert NULL into

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am using JPA for my database mapping, and am trying to do an insertion in the parent (program) and child entities (asset_condition).  When trying to insert into the database, I keep getting  ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("ASSET_CONDITION"."PROGRAM_ID").

How can jpa automatically get this id during insertion for the child record?  What am I doing wrong in my mappings?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Program")
public class Program {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@JsonProperty("id")
private Long id;

@JsonProperty("assetConditions")
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinColumn(name="program_id", nullable=false)
private Set<AssetCondition> assetConditions = null;
}
```

Here is the child entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="asset_condition")
public class AssetCondition implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(nullable=false,name = "program_id", insertable = true)
private Program program;
```

Comment: What is unclear in the message? What don't you understand? Where does Hibernate get the ID to insert in ASSET_CONDITION.PROGRAM_ID? If you can answer this question: why would hibernate insert null then?

Comment: In addition to the explanations in the duplicate, your mapping is wrong, too. Read the documentation. Pay attention to the mandatory mappedBy attribute: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: Okay I just added mappedBy="program" in the Program class @OneToMany annotation.    I thought hibernate would be able to figure out the newly generated program_id from the parent's table insertion.  I didn't think I would manually have to get and set that?

Comment: That's why documentation exists: instead of guessing what you should do, you read it, and you know. It takes a few hours, and saves you days and days of debugging and fixing incorrect code.